# Change scan resolution for Canon TS 9100

Tags: 18.04, scanner, ubuntu-mate

I have a Canon TS 9100 printer/scanner. I use scangearmp2 for the scanning.

I would like to be able to change the scan resolution.

I could not find a way using the panel on the printer.

https://support.usa.canon.com/library/ij/Manual/All/TS9100%20series/EN/UG/ug_s_03_07.html

And scangear has no option to change the resolution.

Is there a way to change the scan resolution?

Using gscan2pdf.

```
gscan2pdf --log=file.log

INFO - Starting gscan2pdf 2.1.0
INFO - Log level DEBUG
INFO - Using en_US.UTF-8 locale
INFO - Startup LC_NUMERIC C
INFO - Reading config from /home/andy/.config/gscan2pdfrc
INFO - Config file version 2
DEBUG - $VAR1 = {};

INFO - Operating system: linux
INFO - DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
INFO - NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.2 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
INFO - Perl version v5.26.1
INFO - Glib-Perl version 1.326
INFO - Glib::Object::Introspection version 0.044
INFO - Built for Glib 2.53.4
INFO - Running with Glib 2.56.4
INFO - Gtk3-Perl version 0.032
INFO - Built for GTK 3.22.30
INFO - Running with GTK 3.22.30
INFO - Gscan2pdf::Document version 2.1.0
INFO - Using PDF::API2 version 2.033
INFO - Using Sane version 1.0.27
INFO - Using libimage-sane-perl version 0.14
DEBUG - $VAR1 = {
          'Blank threshold' => '0.005',
          'Dark threshold' => '0.12',
          'OCR on scan' => 1,
          'OCR output' => 'replace',
          'Page range' => 'all',
          'Paper' => {
                       'A3' => {
                                 'l' => 0,
                                 't' => 0,
                                 'x' => 297,
                                 'y' => 420
                               },
                       'A4' => {
                                 'l' => 0,
                                 't' => 0,
                                 'x' => 210,
                                 'y' => 297
                               },
                       'US Legal' => {
                                       'l' => 0,
                                       't' => 0,
                                       'x' => 216,
                                       'y' => 356
                                     },
                       'US Letter' => {
                                        'l' => 0,
                                        't' => 0,
                                        'x' => 216,
                                        'y' => 279
                                      }
                     },
          'SANE version' => '1.0.27',
          'TMPDIR' => undef,
          'adf-defaults-scan-all-pages' => 1,
          'allow-batch-flatbed' => '',
          'author' => undef,
          'author-suggestions' => undef,
          'auto-open-scan-dialog' => 1,
          'available-tmp-warning' => 10,
          'brightness tool' => 65,
          'cache' => undef,
          'cache options' => 1,
          'cancel-between-pages' => '',
          'close_dialog_on_save' => 1,
          'contrast tool' => 65,
          'convert whitespace to underscores' => '',
          'current_psh' => undef,
          'current_udt' => undef,
          'cwd' => undef,
          'cycle sane handle' => '',
          'date offset' => 0,
          'default filename' => '%Da %DY-%Dm-%Dd',
          'default profile' => undef,
          'default-scan-options' => undef,
          'device' => undef,
          'device blacklist' => undef,
          'downsample' => '',
          'downsample dpi' => 150,
          'frontend' => 'libimage-sane-perl',
          'image type' => undef,
          'keywords' => undef,
          'keywords-suggestions' => undef,
          'libimage-sane-perl version' => '0.14',
          'message' => undef,
          'ocr engine' => 'tesseract',
          'ocr language' => undef,
          'pdf compression' => 'auto',
          'pdf font' => undef,
          'post_save_hook' => '',
          'profile' => undef,
          'ps_backend' => 'pdftops',
          'quality' => 75,
          'restore window' => 1,
          'rotate facing' => 0,
          'rotate reverse' => 0,
          'scan prefix' => '',
          'scan-reload-triggers' => 'mode',
          'scan_window_height' => undef,
          'scan_window_width' => undef,
          'selection' => undef,
          'set_timestamp' => 1,
          'subject' => undef,
          'subject-suggestions' => undef,
          'threshold tool' => 80,
          'threshold-before-ocr' => '',
          'thumb panel' => 100,
          'tiff compression' => undef,
          'title' => undef,
          'title-suggestions' => undef,
          'udt_on_scan' => '',
          'unpaper on scan' => '',
          'unpaper options' => undef,
          'unsharp amount' => 1,
          'unsharp radius' => 0,
          'unsharp sigma' => 1,
          'unsharp threshold' => '0.05',
          'user_defined_tools' => [
                                    'gimp %i'
                                  ],
          'version' => undef,
          'view files toggle' => 1,
          'visible-scan-options' => {
                                      'Paper size' => 1,
                                      'adf-mode' => 1,
                                      'adf_mode' => 1,
                                      'batch-scan' => 1,
                                      'brightness' => 1,
                                      'button-wait' => 1,
                                      'calibration-cache' => 1,
                                      'compression' => 1,
                                      'contrast' => 1,
                                      'gain' => 1,
                                      'l' => 1,
                                      'mode' => 1,
                                      'overscan-bottom' => 1,
                                      'overscan-top' => 1,
                                      'page-height' => 1,
                                      'page-width' => 1,
                                      'pageheight' => 1,
                                      'pagewidth' => 1,
                                      'resolution' => 1,
                                      'source' => 1,
                                      'speed' => 1,
                                      't' => 1,
                                      'threshold' => 1,
                                      'wait-for-button' => 1,
                                      'x' => 1,
                                      'y' => 1
                                    },
          'window_height' => 600,
          'window_maximize' => 1,
          'window_width' => 800,
          'window_x' => undef,
          'window_y' => undef
        };

Perl exited with active threads:
    2 running and unjoined
    0 finished and unjoined
    0 running and detached
```

Edited 6/5/19

```
sudo sane-find-scanner

  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

found USB scanner (vendor=0x04a9 [Canon], product=0x1820 [TS9100 series]) at libusb:002:004
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.
```

Comment: Try XSane instead.

Comment: or gscan2pdf from the Ubuntu Software Center. That program definitely has the ability to change the scan resolution.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Xsane says no devices available. I think that was brought me to use scangearmp2.

Comment: Not long ago I helped a friend install a similar Canon MPF and once the proprietary drivers were installed, it worked fine with XSane.

Comment: @fixit7 - Did you try it with application "simple-scan" ? There in menue "Preferences" you can adjust at register "Quality" the resolution.

Comment: @dschinn1001 When I use simple-scan, it says "No scanners available. Please connect a scanner."

Comment: @fixit7 - and what does xsane say ?

Comment: @dschinn1001 No devices available. I am trying to find a windows scanner program that will work under wine. I tried the software that came with the scanner, but it says I need to log in as a admin to install it. :-( I can set the resolution up to 600 dpi by using the screen on the scanner, but it too does not work.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [open source sane backend](https://github.com/ThierryHFR/scangearmp2) for Canon Pixma scanners, based on the source code of scangearmp2, which allows changing the DPI setting, with [binary releases](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/thierry1970/) for several distros.